# Ckeditor 5 removes HTML comments, how can I preserve them?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, ckeditor5

I used Ckeditor 4 for administrating my email templates, where I hide some backend related information into html comments.
Ckeditor left HTML comments untouched.
I had to upgrade to Ckeditor 5. And now I see that Ckeditor removes all of my HTML comments. Why? And how can I preserve my HTML comments?

Comment: https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5/issues/592

Comment: Yep, thank you for your comment. Finally we moved to TinyMCE what seems to be the only one big wysiwig editor novadays :(

Comment: Wow, TinyMCE looks like nothing I remember from years ago. Has still the "View Source" and **preserves HTML markup Comments** - which is what you're looking for. Yeah, *Tiny* but grown huge. Beware the Pricing.

Comment: Yep, this was my thought too ;) TinyMCE now or Ckeditor now are like a spaceship and a rock. It was my fault to upgrade from Ckeditor4 to Ckeditor5 instead of TinyMCE.

Answer (score 1):

HTML comment support is part of a separate module. Relevant docs can be found at https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/html/html-comments.html.

TL;DR:

> ```
> npm install --save @ckeditor/ckeditor5-html-support
> ```
>
> ```js
> import { HtmlComment } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-html-support';
>
> ClassicEditor
>     .create( document.querySelector( '#editor' ), {
>         plugins: [ HtmlComment, ... ],
>     } )
>     .then( ... )
>     .catch( ... );
> ```

You can find more info about known issues and related features in the docs.

Comment: Perhaps this is the right answer. Anyway, I had so many issues with CkEditor editing HTML content, so finally I chose TinyMCE, what works like charm. I'm pretty sure this is the real solution.